# Produce image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new in MATLAB and I am trying to produce an image which contains every 2nd or 4th pixel.

what I am trying to do:

```
 image1 = false(256,256);

 image2 = false(256,256);

 image1(:, 1:2:end) = true;

 image2(:, 1:4:end) = true;
```

Can anyone tell me if it is correct or not?

Can anyone help me to do it correct?

Comment: This is correct, provided you want a column-wise picture. Use image(1:2:end,2:2:end) = true;  for a chequerboard pattern

Comment: You can see for yourself with `imagesc(image1)` or `imagesc(image2)`

Comment: your code sets every 2nd (or 4th) row - and image2 is not initialised. how about `repmat([1 0;0 0],128,128)`?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. But, when i do the method that I referred above, some lines stops in the middle on the image. why this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct, see the below pictures. first is your `image1`, second your `image2` and the third my chequerboard generated using

```
image3(1:2:end,2:2:end) = true;
imagesc(image3)
```

If your lines stop somewhere in the middle of the plot it is most likely a resolution issue. If you set it to a size of 256*256 pixels or more you probably will not see any lines terminating any more.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Comment: Thats fine! Thank you for your help and for your information!!